# APK file in Mac machine

Tags: android, macos, apk

I have installed Eclipse and SDK in my machine.. But How do I run the .apk file in Mac? I have read some article that I need to run them through command prompt or is it only for WINDOWS based?

Please assist me. Thanks.

Comment: Apk file is yours? Not easier is just use the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can PUSH .apk file in your AVD  from your PC

from DDMS > file explorer > select sdcard

see option right side PUSH file.

Comment: Well if you only have the .apk file then you won't be able to do PUSH or DDMS do you?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to run your apk on the machine and not on a device, then it's probably easier if you just link up an emulator with your eclipse studio.

Comment: How do you link up the emulator with eclipse?