# How to upload images in AVD gellery?

Tags: android, virtual, android-virtual-device

Hello everyone,
           I am working on an android app. i want to know how can i store image in Android virtul device gallery and use it for app

Comment: duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9992472/1289716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load images in your sdcard, of the emulator, for that. [This link](http://www.streamhead.com/android-tutorial-sd-card/) has tutorial for what you require.

Comment: In the link that I shared with you, it also explains how to make an sdcard in an AVD.

Comment: i loaded image in SD card but it not showing in emulator gellery .how can i achieve this.

Comment: In your emulator go to dev tools, there will be a media scan option. Just run it once so that then your photos will be visible in the gallery

Answer (score 0):

for me "media scan" was not solving the issue. so i activated the web cam for the emulator and taken the photo using camera, the image will store into gallery. if you are testing any application where you may have to select image from gallery, then follow this process.